# Leaflet API GeoJSON Error

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to load a GeoJSON file for an interactive map of West Virginia Counties but I am getting an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: wvData is not defined` on line 140.  Can someone help me in figuring out how to resolve this? I am attaching my full code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet Interactive GeoJSON</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .info {
        padding: 6px 8px;
        font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .info h4 {
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        color: #777;
    }

    .legend {
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #555;
    }
    .legend i {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="CountySelection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>  contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
    }).addTo(map);


    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + props.NAME + '</b><br />' + props.POP2010 + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(map);


    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
               d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
               d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
               d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
               d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
               d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
               d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                          '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.POP2010)
        };
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });
    } <!-- ADDED: Line 140 in the source code -->

    geojson = L.geoJson(wvData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
geojson = L.geoJson(wvData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

you haven't yet defined `wvData` anywhere, and looks like you haven't loaded your geojson file yet either.  If you're data is defined in a separate geojson file, you'll need to load it via an ajax request, or checkout the [leaflet-omnivore plugin](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv/).

Comment: mark any as correct?  stackexchange orders questions based on votes and answers, not comments.

Comment: I'm new to this site.  How do I declare a response as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Lyzi Diamond published some blog posts about loading geojson with leaflet. It helped me a lot: http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-and-leaflet-the-other-way/